# System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.' on Content Dialog

Tags: c#, uwp, winui, winui-3

I'm triyng to make a login system in my UWP (WinUI3) app and when I try to lauch de Login Content Dialog it crashes throwing this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

on `await messageDialog.ShowAsync();`

Code on app.xaml.cs:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{

    m_window = new MainWindow();
    m_window.Activate();

    Login();

}

protected async void Login()
{
    var messageDialog = new ContentDialogs.LoginDialog();
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

    if (App.Aplicacao.Utilizador == null)
    {
        m_window.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Content Dialog XAML:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="xizSoft.ContentDialogs.LoginDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:xizSoft.ContentDialogs"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}">

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

Code-behind:

```
public LoginDialog()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: I tested it in a normal UWP app. It works correctly. Then I use the default ContentDialog to test in a WinUI3 UWP app. It still works. And the issue only happens to custom ContentDialog and it should be related to WinUI3. You could ask this in [WinUI issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues?q=is%3Aissue+must+not+specify+different+base+classes) in Github.  Then WinUI team is actively answering WinUI questions there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wait until the contents of the window has been loaded and set the `XamlRoot` property of the `ContentDialog`.

This is how you would display the dialog on startup:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    m_window = new MainWindow();
    m_window.Activate();

    if (m_window.Content is FrameworkElement fe)
        fe.Loaded += (ss, ee) => Login();
}

protected void Login()
{
    var messageDialog = new ContentDialogs.LoginDialog();
    messageDialog.XamlRoot = m_window.Content.XamlRoot;
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

    if (App.Aplicacao.Utilizador == null)
    {
        m_window.Close();
        return;
    }
}

private Window m_window;
```

Comment: This remains an open issue. For more, see: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2504

Comment: Setting the `XamlRoot` property fixed it for me, using WinUI 3.